# Can login with two different emails

Tags: support

I did not find any solution on the web so I am asking here (I hope it is the right place).

I can somehow log in from two different emails. I removed the one I don't need, however, when I login each time to Stack Overflow I keep getting directed to the previous account. I even deleted that account and opened another, using only one email, but still I keep logging in to the same account using two different emails!!

Example:

Here I am using this account:

[image]

However, when I click on my Stack Overflow account I get redirected to my main (which I won't show the name of, but you will see the picture is different).

[image]

And even further! When I click on "meta stack overflow" in my "main", it redirects me to this site, but now with my main account it says I don't have any questions, even though I opened this one! What is going on?

Comment: The best thing to do here is to contact our support team by filling out the form [here](https://stackoverflow.com/contact). Explain what's happening, list the email addresses involved, and they'll be able to help you out.

Comment: @AdamLear Thank you sir, will do!